# Typeahead not working, doesn't log or return anything

Tags: php, json, typeahead

Typeahead loads, because the input changes to what it needs to be, but then does absolutely nothing. Code:

```
$(function() {
 $('.typeahead').typeahead([
    {
        name: 'Search',
        valueKey: 'name',
        remote: {
            url: 'frontpage_search.php?q=%QUERY',

        },
        template: [
            '<p class="name">{{name}}</p>'
        ].join(''),
        engine: Hogan // download and include http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/                                                               
    }
 ]);
```

I include jQuery, typeahead, Hogan, and this file when the page is done loading. JSON is this:

```
[
 {
  "name": "Wind, Earth and Fire",
  "category": "Type"
 },
 {
  "name": "Fire Emblem",
  "category": "Finisher"
 }
]
```

With an application/json header, and it properly validates as JSON. What is going on?

Comment: I don't know if it changes much, but your template doesn't have a closing <p>

Comment: Nope, doesn't, made a mistake in copy/pasting to SO ;). Cheers!

Comment: forgive me for being dumb, but the content in JSON is the result you're seeing when the call goes up to frontpage_search.php?q=%QUERY% right?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't parse the %QUERY% yet, hardcoded JSON for now. For testing purposes.